# !array[0].isEmpty() returning NullPointer?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Here's my code:

```
if (!quizDescs[0].isEmpty()) {
    mDescText.setText(quizDescs[0]);
} else {
    mDescText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

So, when this code runs, and the if condition returns true, everything is fine and dandy, however, if it returns false, it says there's a NullPointerException, and points me to the line of code containing the if statement.

Am I checking the condition right? Why is it returning a NullPointer?!

**ANSWER:**

```
    if (quizDescs[0] == null) {
       mDescText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
       mDescText.setText(quizDescs[0]);
    }
```

Comment: What if `quizDescs[0]` is null?

Comment: you check if your text is empty but you should also check if your list `quizDescs`exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if quizDesc[0] is String, you can do

```
if(!StringUtility.isEmptyOrNull(quizDesc[0])){
 mDescText.setText(quizDescs[0]);
}else {
    mDescText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

By the way,
 Null and being empty is not same

Consider

```
String s; //Initialize to null
String a =""; //A blank string
```

Its always a good practise to use

```
try{
   //Your code here..
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If either `quizDescs` or `quizDescs[0]` are null, you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Obviously, if `isEmpty()` returns false, it means that `isEmpty()` was executed, so `quizDescs[0]` is not null when the condition returns true, and that's why it works.

Either make sure that both `quizDescs` and `quizDescs[0]` is never null, or change the condition to :

```
if (quizDescs != null && quizDescs[0] != null && !quizDescs[0].isEmpty()) {
    ....
} else {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because `quizDescs` is Null so when you try to get `quizDescs[0]` in the condition, you try to get the first item of null object.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible ways the if-line can cause a NullPointerException, is when quizDescs itself is null or the first element quizDescs[0] is null. Try to extract quizDescs into a local variable for debugging purposes and inspect its content.

You can either initialize your array with empty strings or add a check for null - or better review your logic how null is a possible condition. Usually null values should be avoided (see [Bloch, Effective Java 2nd Edition, item 43](http://www.amazon.de/Effective-Java-Programming-Language-Guide/dp/0321356683/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1416302615&sr=8-1&keywords=bloch%20effective%20java%202nd) for a similar case).

Comment: No. The second possible way is that `quizDescs` itself is `null`.